# Find Mac OSX version installed using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

How can I find which version of OSX is installed on my Mac by using AppleScript? I want to install an app programatically and run different pkg files based on the version.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not on a Mac, so there may be a better way to do this, but the first approach that comes to mind is just executing a shell command to query the OS version.

http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html#TNTAG2

http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sw_vers.1.html

Based on these references, you probably want to do something like:

```
set os_version to do shell script "sw_vers -productVersion"
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer! Using `"sw_vers -buildVersion"` at the end, will give you the build version as well. Very helpful if you want to get more detailed information like. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexkaessner/b413b61184dd78309a11f824361516f4) to see it in full action.

Answer (score 20):

Here is how to get OSX version in AppleScript, using built-in functions:

```
set sysinfo to system info
set osver to system version of sysinfo
```

On OS X Mavericks the result is "10.9".

One-liner: `set osver to system version of (system info)`

Comment: This seems to be the most "correct" way, as it relies completely on built-in functions

Comment: Any idea how this might be done in JXA (JavaScript for Automation)? Doesn't seem to have and SystemInfo object.

Answer (score 18):

You can get the OS version as a display string using:

```
set _versionString to system version of (system info)
```

If you want to compare this to another version, be sure to use [`considering numeric strings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html):

```
considering numeric strings
    set _newEnough to _versionString ≥ "10.9"
end considering
```

Otherwise, you can run into problems such as "10.4.11" being less than "10.4.9", or "10.10" being less than "10.9".

You can also use `system attribute`. This lets you get the version number as an integer so that you don't need to worry about comparing dot-separated strings:

```
set _versionInteger to system attribute "sysv" -- 4240 == 0x1090 (Mac OS X 10.9)
set _isMavericksOrBetter to (system attribute "sysv") ≥ 4240 -- 0x1090
set _isMountainLionOrBetter to (system attribute "sysv") ≥ 4224 -- 0x1080
set _isLionOrBetter to (system attribute "sysv") ≥ 4208 -- 0x1070
```

You can also use `system attribute` to get the individual version components without having to parse a string:

```
set _major to system attribute "sys1" -- 10
set _minor to system attribute "sys2" -- 9
set _bugFix to system attribute "sys3" -- 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get version from the Finder app as well

```
tell application "Finder"
    set os_version to version
end tell

display dialog os_version
```

On my machine this displays "10.5.8".

Comment: This returns the Finder version not the OS Version. In my case (6 years later =P) Finder version is 10.10.4 while os version is 10.10.3.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with AppleScript, but AFAIK you can get some info about versions from the shell with the sw_vers command. For example:

```
Macintosh:~ udekel$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.5.6
BuildVersion:   9G55
```

If you can read and parse that from appleScript, that may be a solution, though I'm sure there has to be something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate

set theVersion to do script with command "sw_vers -productVersion"
end tell
```

Edit : It was pointed out that this does open the terminal, and that probably isn't the behavior you want.

Comment: What if Terminal isn't running? This will launch it, scaring most users.

Comment: That's true, however, I was assuming the poster would modify this code to fit their needs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```html
set OSVersion to system version (system info)
if OSVersion as string < "10.9" or OSVersion as string > "10.9.5" then
- Add code to execute if condition met
else
- Add code to execute if condition not met
end if
```